# Execute gulp-tasks via foreverjs

Tags: gulp, forever, forever-monitor, grunt-forever

I am currently struggling with building a script that starts my web-application.

I would like to use foreverjs as I already start my backend with it. My json-file, which will be executed by foreverjs looks like the following:

```
[
 { 
   "uid": "my_backend",
   "append": true,   
   "script": "app.js",
   "sourceDir": "/path/to/backend/"
 },
 {
   "uid": "my_frontend",
   "append": true,
   "script": "???",
   "command": "gulp dist && gulp production"
   "sourceDir": "/path/to/frontend/"
 }
]
```

I am not quite sure what I should use in the frontend. I need to use gulp so I would assume I have to add it in 'command'. However, my script would need to be empty, which is not allowed from foreverjs. Any suggestion of how I can run gulp via foreverjs?

Comment: These days [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) is a far better option ;)

Comment: oh thanks, wasnt aware of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself, using the following script for my init.d:

```
WORKINGDIR=/usr/local/app/my/app
SCRIPT='/usr/local/app/my/app/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js production'
LOG=/usr/local/app/my/app/log
PID=/root/.forever/pids/myapp.pid
FOREVER=/usr/local/node/node-default/bin/forever
UID_APP='myapp'
case "$1" in
    start)
        $FOREVER start --workingDir $WORKINGDIR --uid $UID_APP  -l $LOG/forever.log -o $LOG/forever_out.log -e $LOG/forever_err.log --pidFile $PID -a $SCRIPT
        ;;
    stop)
        $FOREVER stop $UID_APP --pidFile $PID
        ;;
    stopall)
        $FOREVER stopall --pidFile $PID
        ;;
    restartall)
        $FOREVER restartall --pidFile $PID
        ;;
    reload|restart)
        $FOREVER restart -l $LOG/forever.log -o $LOG/forever_out.log -e $LOG/forever_err.log --pidFile $PID -a $SCRIPT
        ;;
    list)
        $FOREVER list
        ;;
    logs)
        $FOREVER logs
        ;;
        *)
            echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/myservice {start|stop|restart|reload|stopall|restartall|list}"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
    exit 0
```

Basically using /path/to/forever start --workingDir '**mydir**' /path/to/gulp [**gulpTask**] works.